# RazorEngine evaluation issue with .js code

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, d3.js, razorengine

I am using RazorEngine to evaluate some JavaScript code and I ran into an issue where it fails to compile. Here's an example:

```
var someBarChart = d3.select("@Model.DivId").append("svg")
.attr("width", barChartWidth + barChartMargin.left + barChartMargin.right)
.attr("height", barChartHeight + barChartMargin.top + barChartMargin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + barChartMargin.left + "," + barChartMargin.top + ")");
```

The culprit here is "" marks around `@Model.DivId`. 
Can somone point me to a way to evaluate that particular example?

I am expecting this result:

```
var someBarChart = d3.select("someDivId").append("svg")
.attr("width", barChartWidth + barChartMargin.left + barChartMargin.right)
.attr("height", barChartHeight + barChartMargin.top + barChartMargin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + barChartMargin.left + "," + barChartMargin.top + ")");
```

Also, it fails on me when I try to evaluate something like this:

```
@Model.BarChartName.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + barChartHeight + ")")
.call(xAxis);
```

In this case I was expecting a result like this:

```
someBarChart.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + barChartHeight + ")")
.call(xAxis);
```

Like I mentioned I am using RazorEngine and its configured by default to decode Html. I also tried a case of using `var someBarChart = d3.select("@Raw(Model.Div)").append("svg")` but that fails to evaluate as well.

All ideas are appreciated. 
Thank you,

Comment: Typically what I have done in the past is to render the divid into a data-attribute of whatever it is you need, then reference it in javascript via $(this).data('divid') or some such.  That way you can also move the javascript out of the view into it's own file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of double quotes, use single quotes when you want to use the razor value as a string in javascript:

```
d3.select('@Model.DivId')
```

Answer (score 0):

@Robert McKee

I was actually able to solve it using this syntax:

```
var @Model.DivName = d3.select("@(Model.DivId)").append("svg")
```

This is evaluating correctly. Thank you for the suggestion though.